# Cannot assign to read-only in class constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I understand that `readonly` properties can only be assigned a value within a class constructor. However, this TypeScript error appears inside a constructor. I suspect it is because of the array method handler.

```js
class MyClass {
    readonly alpha: number

    constructor(settings: Options) {
        ;(Object.keys(settings) as Array<keyof Options>).forEach((key: keyof Options) => {
            // This is not allowed (error: Cannot assign to '...' because it is a read-only property.)
            this[key] = settings[key]

            // Also not allowed
            this.alpha = settings.alpha
        })

        // This is allowed
        this.alpha = settings.alpha

        // This is also allowed
        const key = 'alpha'
        this[key] = settings.alpha
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AzlAvFA3gKCkKgEMAbMAC2IC4oUBXAWwCMIAnAo5t4gNyVoMW7ToQDGVNqQQRBTVhwC+ePGNLE0GALIgAwus25RUNhGIATVKRAlyVOcI5ETZyymtRufAXXkjnphZWNhLEUjIOCirOYqhowGz0YsBIbAAUaBDAiCgA5mi0cIhxAJRGzs4A3FBpMMwAVhDJAHQA1hAgaBlZOfllGlAAgmw8IAA87SBIAGaw8MjoAHwlzdOpAKLEEmlpk7STM3PF6GWYi+UVlwD0V1AAKhQIGE90SMC2pEgA7hDmNexsVK0XTEFAoN4kTQIXIoKApKAAcmayIRniaxHomSgCHeL2ILgsAFpglAwIDIGxQM0SsZLoRgI80ABtSYAXSwUEy2QQeWZbOidOcNyGpDQSFe7zInx+5lpdIZT2aZEo+OwXN6aCVdmIcsIihpuqgwoeLzxpGlv0NCs1yqoHPVPPyWpVVsZzS8-HtPUdmo9SFditC4Wgau9vOaQekEAF11uJueGDIYo+30tgti6Hekw5CNtxARAb5HXZoe54bzxmUyiAA)

Why does this happen? Is it possible to avoid this error while still using an array method?

Comment: Just use a loop instead of the `forEach` method?

Comment: Since it's a callback, it could be invoked after the constructor call is completed. Of course, it's `forEach` and that's supposed to be "sync", but TypeScript treats all callbacks the same and that's why it disallows you from assigning to readonly properties on `this`.

Comment: TS allows you to assign read-only props to non-read-only props and vice versa (see [ms/TS#13347](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13347)) so one workaround is to do such an assignment first, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5O3VW).  Does that meet your needs or am I missing something? (Pls ping me via @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Answer (score 0):

```
type Options = {
    alpha: number
    bravo: number
    charlie: number
}


function recordKeys<T extends Record<string | number, unknown>>(
    record: T
): ((keyof T & string) | (`${keyof T & number}`))[] {
    return Object.keys(record);
}

class MyClass {
    readonly alpha!: number
    readonly bravo!: number
    readonly charlie!: number

    constructor(settings: Options) {
        for (const key of recordKeys(settings)) {
            this[key] = settings[key];
        }
        for (const key of Object.keys(settings) as (keyof Options)[]) {
            this[key] = settings[key];
        }
        // honestly, in such cases I generally don't care and just 
        Object.assign(this, settings)
        // end either `alpha!: number` or `alpha = 0`
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I particularly like that `recordKeys` function. I was hoping to find out _why_ TS reports the error. Your solutions unfortunately creates a different issue—that it cannot be sure we're actually initializing all readonly properties—and that requires a non null assertion.